# Cant get the height of the div in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vml

I have assigned the `80% height` of the `viewport` to my `div` as height. In Button click I have displayed the height of the div. This works fine in ie9, ie10. But in ie7, ie8 `$("#divContainer").height()` is 0. Am I doing anything wrong and how to get the height of the div in IE7, IE8(vml)

```
   <html style="height:100%;">
   <body style="height:100%;">


    <div id="divContainer" style="height:100%; border:2px solid #ff0000">
     </div> 
      <button id="button1"></button>

      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#button1").click(function()
                {
                    alert($("#divContainer").height());

                });
            });

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 2):

For IE you may try pure javascript solution

`var height = getElementById("divContainer").clientHeight;`

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly include jQuery Library in your Code's head section and use .css("height") instead of .height()
Modified code is as below

```
<html style="height:100%;">
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">

<button id="button1" value="text"></button>
<div id="divContainer" style="height:100%; border:2px solid #ff0000">
 </div> 


  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#button1").click(function()
            {
                alert($("#divContainer").css("height"));

            });
        });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Note I have taken Button above the container.

Comment: i am getting 0px by using css

Comment: I am getting 628px on Firefox

Comment: the problem is in vml. that is ie7, ie8

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jquery - Height](http://api.jquery.com/height/) option

or

use jquery with css option of any properties of tag or id.
like

```
<div id="divContainer" style="height:100%; border:2px solid #ff0000">
 </div>     

  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#button1").click(function()
            {
                alert($("#divContainer").css("height"));
                //also set the height too as
                $("#divContainer").css("height", "80%");

            });
        });
```